# Excel VBA W7 / W10

Tags: vba, excel

I've succesfully created a userform based on excel VBA. 
It allows data entry and via macro's to be added to Accessdb.

This all works fine. One problem though, I created this on Office 2010. Now there is a upgrade coming to W10 and Office 2016 and this gives a problem. Somehow it's not compatible and gives an error when I try it on an already upgraded system. 
Checked its libraries and it shows me an update version of Microsoft office 16.0 object library. On office 2010 this is 14.0. Besides that there is no upgraded library.

[image]
[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is that the references dialog as it appears on the O2016 machine, or the O2010? I suspect your problem is the Windows Common Controls library.

Comment: Yes this is the O2016 machine. Other has 2014. Whats with the Windows common controls library?

Comment: Is it 64bit Office as well as Windows?

Comment: Yes its a 64 bit.

Comment: The common controls won't work in 64bit Office - they are just not compatible.

Comment: Any way around this or how to solve it?

Comment: Don't use the common controls. Which one(s) are you using?

Comment: TBH: no idea. I created this with 0 knowledge ( as you might already notice) just expanded the project bit by bit using the Excel VBA program. Would not know wich belongs to what.

Comment: think ive got it. its the date picker that gives the problems